# How can I use shutil.make_archive() within the app context in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask and have built a Flask website. I'm trying to have a routine run every 12 hours using `BackgroundScheduler` from `apscheduler`, which uses `shutil.make_archive()` to copy the directory and zip the file into a separate location.

When I manually run the backup from the front-end page that I have, the backup runs fine with zero issues, however the automatic backups throw this error:

"RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information."

I've done a decent amount of research on context in Flask but it's still not really making sense to me, an example of my code is provided here:

```
#views.py (blueprint of the app)

def backup_auto():
    # Gets current date
    today = date.today()
    current_date = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    str(current_date)

    # Gets current time
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H.%M.%S")
    str(current_time)
    
    # Defines file path and makes an archive of the directory
    temp_path = path + current_date + " " + current_time
    shutil.make_archive(temp_path, 'zip', source_dir)

# Automatically performs backup at set rate
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=backup_auto, trigger="interval", seconds=1000)
scheduler.start()
# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

I've messed around a bit using `with app.app_context():` in my `__init__.py` file but I can't seem to get it to work. I don't think I'm really understanding how Flask context applies here. Any suggestions on how I can get this to work or better alternatives? Thanks!